# Text animation, creating typewriting-like effect in c#

Tags: c#, xaml, text, timer, textblock

This is what I did in MainPage.xaml.cs to create the text animation effect:

```
private readonly double TEXT_TIMER = 30.0;
private int index;

 private void updateText(String text)
    {
        _text = text;
        index = 0;
        MainTextBlock.Text = "";            

        _textTimer.Tick += _textTimer_Tick;
        _textTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(TEXT_TIMER);
        _textTimer.Start();
    }

 private void _textTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (index < _text.Length)
        {
            string s = _text[index].ToString();
            MainTextBlock.Text += s;
            index++;
        }
        else
        {
        _textTimer.Stop();
        }
    }
```

I have a list of texts/strings and also a button, say `NextButton` on the MainPage.xaml. The `updateText` method is in the click event of `NextButton`, and what it does is to fetch a text from the list of texts/strings and update the textblock using the animation effect.

But I realised that as I continued to click on the `NextButton`, it was as if the value of `TEXT_TIMER` was reducing and the animation effect happened more rapidly until there was no animation anymore (i.e. the text just appeared in the textblock without any effects).

Anybody got any idea why this is happening and how I can fix it?

**EDIT**:
I have included code to stop the timer after the textblock has been updated with the hopes that solves possible multiple Tick callbacks but nothing still.

Comment: See if your program flow is registering for the Tick event multiple times.  If you call updateText more than once, that will happen, which will cause you to receive a series of Tick callbacks in quick succession for each tick.

Comment: @DanBryant sorry, I didn't get you at first. I moved `_textTimer.Tick += _textTimer_Tick;` into the constructor and it works good now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On [Dan Bryant's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/206394/dan-bryant) advice:

My program flow was registering for the Tick event multiple times beacuse I put it into the `updateText` method which got called multiple times during program run. All I had to do was move that line of code where the Tick event is registered, `_textTimer.Tick += _textTimer_Tick;` into the constructor, i.e after `InitializeComponent()` and problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

It's not that `TEXT_TIMER` value is reducing, but `_textTimer` is not stopping, so you have multiple timer ticks.
Try adding `_textTimer.Stop()` at the start of `updateText()` method.

Comment: that didn't work. I also tried adding `else { _textTimer.Stop(); }` in the `_textTimer_Tick` but no success with that either.

Comment: Try moving `_textTimer.Tick += _textTimer_Tick;` right after timer initialization as @Dan Bryant suggested